# webservice (iisexpress) keeps files open

Tags: c#, web-applications, iis-express

I need to create a sema4 file that restricts other sessions from trying to open/write to a database if another session is already trying to do the same 'transaction' By transaction, in this case make a similar booking that is already 'in progress'.

Here's the code:

```
  HttpSessionState ss = HttpContext.Current.Session;
  string sessionID = ss.SessionID;
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dataDirectory + "Semaphores");
  string facilityIDExt = requestedFacilityID.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
  string sema4File = string.Format("{0}.{1:yyyyMMdd}.{2}", sessionID, RequestedStartDT, facilityIDExt);
  sema4FilePath = Path.Combine(di.FullName, sema4File);
  File.Create(sema4FilePath);

  FileInfo[] fiPaths = di.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", facilityIDExt));
  bool bookingInProgress = true;
  int waitPeriod = 60;
  while (waitPeriod > 0 && bookingInProgress)
  {
    fiPaths = di.GetFiles(string.Format("*.{0}", facilityIDExt));
    bookingInProgress = false;
    foreach (FileInfo item in fiPaths)
      if (item.Name.Contains(string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}.{1}", RequestedStartDT, facilityIDExt)) && item.Name != sema4File)
      {
        if (item.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1))
        {
          bookingInProgress = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    waitPeriod = waitPeriod - 5;
  }
```

The idea is that the actual booking will take much less than 60 seconds to record in the database however in the meantime, no other booking requests will be permitted.

The problem that I am having is that when I call the following:

```
        if (File.Exists(sema4FilePath))
         File.Delete(sema4FilePath);
```

iisexpress won't delete the file as it is 'in use'. It is 'in use' by iisexpress.

I assume that this will happen with iis as well.

I don't understand why iisexpress keeps the sema4 file open?

How do I get around the 'in use' issue when I want to delete the sema4 file?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
File.Create(sema4FilePath);
```

You get back a FileStream. You should close that to release it. Preferably wrap it into a using:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(sema4FilePath)) {
  // Do you stuff
}
```

Or just directly close if you don't use the contents:

```
File.Create(sema4FilePath).Close();
```